# JSON return nil check?

Tags: json, swift, api, null, jsondecoder

```
struct AltWX: Decodable {
var raw: String
}

typealias AltMetarDecode = [String: AltWX]



do 
{ 
    let aero = try decoder.decode(AltMetarDecode.self, from: data) 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.DownloadOrderCode == 3 
        {
            if let Ab = aero[ICAO1]
            {
                self.Alternate1Metar.text = Ab.raw
                UserDefaults.standard.set(Ab.raw, forKey: "MetarCodeAlt1")
            }
        }
        ...
```

The above code accesses a Json like this:

```
"xxxx": { "raw": "Test"
```

so `Ab.raw` would print Test

How can I add an error check to see if ICAO1 exists and also if Ab.raw exists, and if any values are nil return something? I read the usual catch responses to Json but not sure how to format it for this case specifically especially that i have a lot of order codes and each has to be checked separately.

Comment: If `ICAO1` exists then `raw` exists, too, since it's declared non-optional.

Comment: Ah I see, how about if ICA01 exists and raw is empty ("")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks if `ICAO1` exists and `raw` is empty

```
if let raw = aero["ICAO1"]?.raw, raw.isEmpty {

}
```

Please name variables lowercased according to the naming convention.

Comment: and for raw is not empty? just so i can keep it all in one function then add an else if it doesn't exist or is empty

Comment: Put a `!` in front of the expression: `!raw.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a do try catch block for this.

```swift
enum ContentError: Error {
    case missingICAO1
    case missingRaw
    case orderCodeError
}

// not sure of the return types from the decode block ???
func setValues(values: AltMetarDecode) throws {
   guard self.DownloadOrderCode == 3 else { throw ContentError.orderCodeError }
   guard let Ab = values[ICA01] else { throw ContentError.missingICA01 }
   guard Ab.raw != nil else { throw ContentError.missingRaw }

   self.Alternate1Metar.test = Ab.raw
   UserDefaults.standard.set(Ab.raw, forKey: "MetarCodeAlt1")
}

do {
   let aero = try decoder.decode(AltMetaDecode.self, from data)
   try DispatchQueue.main.async {
      setValues(values: aero)
   }
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Setting up a function to throw errors may not be the most code efficient way, but to me it makes the code clear and readable.